# Robust regression with empty pandas dataFrame columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I have a pandas DataFrame. For example, I have the following:

`column1  column2  column3
    34       nan      3
    45       nan      1
    45       nan      3
    45       nan      3
    46       nan      3
    45       nan      nan
    45       nan      3
    47       nan      5
    45       nan      3
    50       nan      3`

I would like to do some regression using [Theil Sen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator). I wrote the following script:

```
def LR(df)
    line = {}
    slope = {}
    for k, v in df.iteritems():
        if v.empty:
            pass  # This is to check if a column is empty
        else:
            xm = np.ma.masked_array(df.index.values, mask=np.isnan(df[k]).compressed()
            ym = np.ma.masked_array(df[k], mask=np.isnan(df[k]).compressed()
            res = stats.theislopes(ym, xm, 0.90)
            line[k] = res[1] + res[0] * xm
            slope[k] = res[0]
    return line, slope
```

The problem is that I have this error:

> ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,).

When I use the debug mode, it seems that the error occurs when the a specific column is empty.

What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using sklearn as follow:

```
for k,v in df.iteritems():

  xm=np.ma.masked_array(df.index.values,mask=np.isnan(df[k])).compressed()
  ym=np.ma.masked_array(df[k], mask=np.isnan(df[k])).compressed()

  if len(xm)>0 and len(ym)>0:
    model=TheilSenRegressor()
    xm=np.reshape(len(xm),1)
    ym=np.reshape(len(ym),1)

    model.fit(xm,ym)
    return model.intercept_, model.coef_
  else: pass
```